# MyEclipse JPA reverse engineering with custom column names

Tags: java, jpa, myeclipse

I am reverse engineering the database table to *JPA* entities. I use *MyEclipse IDE* , and *JPA* persistance implemenation chosen is *EclipseLink2.5.0 Kepler.*

After connecting to the embedded *DerbyDB*, I could reverse engineer a table named Productline to generate corresponding JPA entity Productline.java and the related jpa files.
I followed this tutorial - http://docs.myeclipseide.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.genuitec.myeclipse.persistence.doc%2Fhtml%2Fquickstarts%2Fjpa%2Findex.html

The **Productline** table has the following columns:

```
productline; textdescription; htmldescription
```

The generated `Productline.java` has the below code snippet,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTLINE", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
public class Productline implements java.io.Serializable {
    // Fields
    private String productline;
    private String textdescription;
    private String htmldescription;
```

Actually I need the 'textdescription' columname as 'TXTDESC'
ie

```
@Column(name="TXTDESC")
private String textdescription;
```

**Question :**

I like to know from experienced guys,**if there is any strategy/logic where either -**

(a) **I can change this column name during the reverse engineering process ?** [I saw the usage of `SessionCustomizer` , but that is for generic logic or naming convention for all tables and columns. In my case, the column name is actually looked up and varies for each table.]
  (or)

(b) **I can do the reverse engineering first and then any sort of extra code generation mechanism where I can specify the custom names for each of the table columns reverse engineered?**

Note: I understand that we can do it programmatically line by line for each column name, but I am trying to see if this can be leveraged with the help of MyEclipse JPA reverse engineering support or any other logic/strategy, as there would be 100+schemas with 100+tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do because you can't change the column name in the table by this process. You would have to alter the table in the database to do that and then use this process.

However, you can alter the property name in the generated Java class by, instead of clicking Finish in step 3, click Next, then Next again. Now expand the Productline table and select any of the columns to see the modifications you can make to what gets generated. If you click the table itself, you can change the class name that gets generated for the table.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say on first line. yes, you're right. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Engineering the schema to get JPA entities is a process that you do one time, during development, and it's a process that doesn't need to be 100% automated unless you expect rapid schema changes that you are expected to follow. Just do it once and keep track of them by hand.

Comment: Thank you, however this doesn't help me with the problem in hand, I have mentioned this option as part of 'Note'.